# DynamoDB "ValidationException: Query key condition not supported"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I can not solve the problem with Query key condition not supported
it works fine if i remove "and #position = :position" from KeyConditionExpression

Hope you will help me.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is position attribute defined as sort key  and it is numeric as well?

Comment: Yes it is, it is like a secondary index

Comment: Thanks mate you really helped me with that sort key :)) i have forgotten to put sort key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position` attribute should be defined as `sort key` in order to use it in `KeyConditionExpression`.

Please define `position` attribute as sort key for GSI `category-index`.